# Getting a word after a specific character in PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the words in a string where a specific character stands before, in this case, its the `:` character.

> textexjkladjladf :theword texttextext :otherword :anotherword

From this snippet the expected output will be:

- theword
- otherword
- anotherword

How do i do this with PHP?

Comment: Alright, but how do i get this and convert it into an array?

Comment: Search the manual for [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

```
$string = "textexjkladjladf :theword texttextext :otherword :anotherword";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/(?<=:)\w+/', $string, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $item) {
    echo $item."<br />";
}
```

Output is:

```
theword
otherword
anotherword
```

The array what you want is the `$matches[0]`

Comment: Thanks! that did it, but how do you include the `:` in the result and make it an associtave array?

Comment: check this, this is really similar than yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27356542/advanced-tag-based-search-string-parsing/27356932#27356932

Comment: Thanks, but these regular expressions are really hard to read... I still dont know why yours is working :P

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting those words without Regular Expression can be:

Use explode(' ',$str) to get all the words.

Then loop the words and check which one starts with ':'.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$str = 'textexjkladjladf :theword texttextext :otherword :anotherword';
$tab = exlode(':',$str);
print_r($tab);
//if echo entry 0 =>
echo $tab[0]; // => textexjkladjladf
```

Comment: This is not the desired result