# Advanced tag based search string parsing

Tags: php

I am trying to make an advanced search with tags that can associate specific keywords to specific fields like so:

**search**: test message **status**: closed **user**: john

Wondering what is the best way to parse the string into a nice array like so:

["search" => "test message", "status" => "closed", "user" => "john"]

At the moment I am doing it like this:

```
$parse = explode(':', $_REQUEST['q']);
$parsed = [];
foreach($parse AS $key => $value) {
  if($key == (count($parse) - 1))
   break;
  $next = explode(' ', $parse[($key + 1)]);
  $last = array_pop($next);
  $next = implode(' ', $next);
  $parse[($key + 1)] = $last;
  $parsed[$parse[$key]] = !empty($next) ? $next : $last;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be much much easier if you have your client submit a query string with the parameters already split: `yoursite.com?search=test message&status=closed&user=john`

Comment: That is not a problem. I can do the above parsing in JS on submit. I want to find a better way of parsing the string into tag/value pairs. Preferably the way it is done by Apple, Google in their email applications for example. A way that would work under all conditions. I am not sure this solution would work very well.

Comment: How are your users composing that search string? Are they manually typing it in or is your client side code generating it from a form or something?

Comment: They are manually typing it in.

Comment: Oh... hold on... so you have working code here... If there is no actual problem with the code you have other than the fact that you think it can be done "better/cleaner" then I think that this post would be better suited to [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/): `"Code Review Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews."`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution, but I am preatty sure, that is most elegant if we could do it with regexp, I've just can't figure out the pattern:

```
$string = "search: test message status: closed user: john";
$pieces = explode(' ', $string);
$values = array();
$array = array();
foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
    if (strpos($piece, ":") !== false) {
        if (count($values)) {
            $array[$key] = join(" ", $values);
        }
        $key = rtrim($piece, ":");
        $values = array();
    } else {
        $values[] = $piece;
    }
}
$array[$key] = join(" ", $values);
var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array
  'search' => string 'test message' (length=12)
  'status' => string 'closed' (length=6)
  'user' => string 'john' (length=4)
```

**EDIT**

Based on tntu comment, here is a version with regex:

```
$string = "search: test message status: closed user: john";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/(([a-z]+):([a-z0-9 ]+(?![a-z:])))+/is', $string, $matches);
$i = 0;
foreach ($matches[2] as $key) {
    if (isset($matches[3][$i])) {
        $array[$key] = trim($matches[3][$i]);
    } else {
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: /(([a-z]+):([a-z0-9 ]+(?![a-z:])))+/is

Comment: I'm hoping that there will not be problems where due to the limitations of accepted characters that I have as I will be querying mysql with fulltext indexing doing full and partial matches only. For a more relaxed policy of accepted characters things could get tricky. I'm planning to add js based input validation and prevent submission or searching if the string is not valid.

Comment: Always do server side validation, because js could be vulnerable.

Comment: On the server side I do sanitization. Stipping everything but alphanumeric, space and colon. No risk there.